# Problem with Skip and Take in NHibernate 3 Linq query

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

Using linq to NHibernate (NHibernate v3) I have the following LINQ query:

```
    var session = this.GetSession();
    var rgn = this.Get(regionId);

    var query = from t in session.Query<Tag>()
                where
                    !(
                        from trn in session.Query<Translation>() 
                        where trn.Region.Id == regionId 
                        select trn.Tag.Id
                     )
                     .Contains(t.Id)

                select new Translation() {Id = t.Id, Tag = t, Region = rgn, TagTranslation=""};

    var count = query.Count();
    var untranslatedTags = query.Skip((page - 1)*pageSize).Take(pageSize);
    var countAfterSkipAndTake = untranslatedTags.Count();
    return untranslatedTags.ToList();
}
```

the count variable does indeed return the expected value. However countAfterSkipAndTake returns the same value. I would hve expected it to return pageSize (which in this case is 15). The final line untranslatedTags.ToList() returns an exception. I believe LINQ to NHibernate is not fully implemented, before I try and download the trunk can anyone see anything obvious I've done wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess, as I've had a similar problem in the past, is that the `var count = query.Count();` is forcing nHibernate to compile the query, and therefore any future amends to it are futile as it's already been executed.

To test this out, remove that line and see if the `countAfterSkipAndTake` is now 15.

Comment: Unfortunately not. After trying all sorts of different things it looks as though NHibernate's LINQ implementation doesn't like the select projection. I updated my LINQ statement to include the skip and take and replaced the select projection with a simple select() call and it worked. In another statement I wanted to use the Union operator but I get an exception stating that the union operator isn't implimented yet. It seems as though LINQ to NHibernate still has several issues.